# How to communicate Django custom API with another process?

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, process

I've searched for a solution everywhere but I just can't find anything that accomplishes what I need.

The problem is the following:
I have a Django server that listens to requests, said requests are usually in Json format, the API handles said requests by reading parameters from the Json object contained in it, the problem is that to handle some of them I need data contained in another process running parallel to the server

In other words, I have let's say foo.py running, which collects sensor data and changes actuators accordingly, foo.py is also a webclient that gets data from the server and sends sensor data to it. Keep in mind, foo.py was created using OOP, meaning everything that interacts with or is created by foo.py is an object.

In parallel, I have the Django server running, receiving requests from the same server, these requests are meant to serve as orders, such as changing actuator states, changing sensor pins, etc. The problem arises when I have to get data from foo.py or change something in foo.py

The API contains an object from foo.py, which is the one that uses to get data

I can post code if needed

Comment: Yes please post the code and try to formulate clearly your problem and your question. Else it is hard to understand and you will get unlikely an answer.

Comment: So foo.py is another service, Django will invoke it, what problem you facing with this?